# Trigger Talend jobs dynamically based on metadata stored in config table

Tags: talend

We need to build an orchestration framework that would allow triggering Talend jobs dynamically based on metadata that conceptually looks like this:

| Job name | Dependency |
| --- | --- |
| Job1 |  |
| Job2 | Job1 |
| Job3 | Job1 |
| Job4 | Job2,Job3 |

For the example above, we need Job1 to be executed first. Then, upon completion of Job1, Job2 and Job3 need to start in parallel. Finally, when both Job2 and Job3 are complete Job4 needs to start.

To implement this framework I need a way to trigger Talend jobs dynamically, based on the job names that I pull from the config. So far I thought of two options, but neither is ideal:

1. tRunJob component with **Use dynamic job** flag. The downside of this approach is that we still need to list the superset of child jobs in the **Job** parameter, and we will need to change the master job every time we add a new child job. This would not scale well for our scenario since we will need to orchestrate 100+ jobs and are looking for a way to publish new ones without touching the framework.
2. Talend orchestration API. I see many methods under Tasks in the API documentation, but I could not find one that would allow me to trigger a task. I guess I could get around it by making the API call to schedule a task to run (e.g. a minute from the current time), but this does not seem to be the cleanest way to trigger a task.

Is there anything I am missing when considering these two options? Are there any other options?

Really appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet would be using the metaservlet API, as a tRunJob with dynamic jobs will require you to change the job each time a new job is added.  With the Metaservlet [API](https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/7.3/administration-center-metaservlet-api/metaservlet-commands), you could use a combination of `getTaskIdByName` to get the task id using the job name, then launch it using `runTask`

Comment: Thank you @ibrahim-mezouar! Your answer confirms my understanding of how tRunJob works. For API - we use Talend Cloud edition, so I believe I am not able to use Metaservlet API. However, after seeing has "runTask" method, I've researched Talend Cloud API further and found "processing/executions" endpoint that has a method to execute a task. Thanks again!